# Private Constructor in SqlConnection class Takes Parameter SqlConnection class

Tags: c#, oop, sqlconnection

I was inspection `SqlConnection` with [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

I noticed that there is a private constructor, interestingly it takes as parameter a `SqlConnection` class.

The main question I wonder
* Why an `SqlConnection` takes a `SqlConnection` class?
* And what it the use of private constructors?

```
private SqlConnection(SqlConnection connection)
{
    this._reconnectLock = new object();
    this._originalConnectionId = Guid.Empty;
    this.ObjectID = Interlocked.Increment(ref _objectTypeCount);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    this.CopyFrom(connection);
    this._connectionString = connection._connectionString;
    if (connection._credential != null)
    {
        SecureString password = connection._credential.Password.Copy();
        password.MakeReadOnly();
        this._credential = new SqlCredential(connection._credential.UserId, password);
    }
}

public SqlConnection()
{
    this._reconnectLock = new object();
    this._originalConnectionId = Guid.Empty;
    this.ObjectID = Interlocked.Increment(ref _objectTypeCount);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    this._innerConnection = DbConnectionClosedNeverOpened.SingletonInstance;
}
```

**Update:**
With the guide of [Hvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530135/1766716) I found one usage:

```
object ICloneable.Clone()
{
  SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(this);
  Bid.Trace("<sc.SqlConnection.Clone|API> %d#, clone=%d#\n", this.ObjectID, sqlConnection.ObjectID);
  return (object) sqlConnection;
}
```

Comment: As for your second question, private constructors are commonlly used in the [singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Comment: Looks like *copy constructor* in C++

Comment: I'm guessing this is how it handles mixed mode authentication (sql vs windows). Again, I am guessing.

Comment: Also, note that .NET Reflector has an `Analyze` feature that can tell you lots of information about other pieces of code that reference the one that you're looking at.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use Reflector for that, the source code is [freely available online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,2e72f136ea7b6530,references).

What's more, the freely available online version of the source code immediately shows you what the point of that constructor is: it's used in `SqlConnection`'s implementation of `ICloneable.Clone`. The new connection's properties are supposed to match the old connection's properties, and the easiest way to do that is by copying the properties. The class designers decided that you shouldn't attempt to clone an `SqlConnection` by creating a new `SqlConnection`, but clearly, *some* new connection object needs to be created, and the other public constructors aren't as good a match for the implementation of `Clone`. So, a new constructor was created, and its access was restricted so that it could not be (mis)used by others.

Comment: Thanks. I found also other usages of this private constructor with "Find Usages Advanced" but didn't have time to inspect detailed. Will update the question according to new usages and probably mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @guneysus I'm very surprised by that. It shouldn't be possible, if the constructor is `private` and isn't otherwise exposed by the class. Admittedly it is a `partial class`, but as far as I know that's just because [this file](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionHelper.cs) is used as a template to insert code common to all `DbConnection`-derived classes, and it doesn't call any constructor either. I'll wait to see what you find.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had checked the 'Include Overloads'. :) In short, I found only one usage `object ICloneable.Clone()`